# Are $\arcsin x$ and $\arccos x$ equal up to a constant?

Tags: calculus, integration

Are the functions $\arcsin x$ and $\arccos x$ equal up to a constant?

When I was solving the indefinite integral $\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ I got two different results depending on the kind of the trigonometric substitution I make:

$\displaystyle \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=-\arcsin x$, if $x=\sin \theta$

$\displaystyle  \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\arccos x$, if $x=\cos\theta$

Where's my mistake?

Comment: You mean like $\arcsin x + \arccos x = \pi/2$  ?

Comment: @A---B I didn't understand, if $-\arcsin x=\arccos x$, then $\arcsin x+ \arccos x=0$, no?

Comment: $-\arcsin x \ne \arccos x$ but $\arccos x =\pi/2 - \arcsin x$. So,  $\arccos x 
 + C=C_2 - \arcsin x$, where $C, C_2 \in \Bbb R$ and $C_2 = C + \pi/2$.

Comment: @user42912 No! What you can deduce for your computations is that $\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\arcsin x+C_1$ and that $\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=-\arccos x+C_2$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants. Note, by the way, that there is an error in your signs.

Comment: @A---B ha ok, I got it. Thank you!

Comment: @user42912 No problem :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No mistake. It turns out that$$\left(\forall x\in\left[-1,1\right]\right):\arcsin(x)+\arccos(x)=\frac\pi2.$$It is easy to justify this geometrically.

Comment: I didn't understand, if $-\arcsin x=\arccos x$, then $\arcsin x+ \arccos x=0$, no?

Comment: @user42912 Read my comment to your question.

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much! Muito obrigado :)

Comment: @user42912 De nada. ;)

Comment: @José Carlos Santos: In the question there are no bounds given for the defining integrals. This identity also appears to hold outside the normal geometric bounds of [-1,1] for x, i.e. when both arcsin(x) and arccos(x) give values in the complex plane.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong bounds are given ($x=sin (\theta)$ and $x=cos(\theta)$) as there is no indication that $\theta$ is complex.